# Java classpath issues

Tags: compiler-errors, classpath, runtime-error, antlr

I'm having trouble getting my program to run from the command line.  I'm executing it from the  src folder and the files are stored in the package proj2.

So when I run 
    `java -cp "proj2/*;proj2/antlr-3.5.jar" proj2.myClass`

I receive an `"Error: Could not find or load main class"`

If I remove the classpath and just write
    `java proj2.myClass`

I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

How can I run the program using the classpaths correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `java proj2.myClass` tries to run the main method from class **myClass** (name should be upper case by convention) in package **proj2**.

If **myClass** is declared with `package proj2;` there has to be a file **myClass.class** in a subfolder **proj2** of a classpath entry, in the given example it should be  `java -cp ".;proj2/antlr-3.5.jar" proj2.myClass`, so `proj2.myClass` can be found searching from `.`.

If you don't need antlr-3.5 you can ommit `.`.

If your class has no package declared it has to be `java -cp "proj2;proj2/antlr-3.5.jar" myClass`.

You should also avoid mixing class files and jar files in the same folder or accessible through the same classpath entry, but separating jars and classes subtrees.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me straighten everything out